# TextView in the right side of parent

Tags: android, xml, textview

So I'm trying to put a textview to the left side of an image that fills the parent. Any ideas how to do it in XML? are there any ways to put the textview with witdh 200dp and height 300dp  but in the right corner of the parent?

TY

Here's my code for the imageview to the left:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="300dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        />
```

Note that I am new with this

Comment: I am confused because you say you want the text on the left side but want the text in the right corner of the parent

Comment: I want to use 2 textviews. one in the top-left corner and one in the top0right corner

Comment: Could you please post more of your code, including the `Layout` that you're using?

Comment: Will do when i get home cause i'm at work now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to align where but if you want something aligned on the right you can use this in a RelativeLayout:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: I am in a LinearLayout, orientation = horizontal. I want the last view in the layout (which is a LinearLayout itself) to be held to the right of the parent. I tried this attribute and it had 0 effect.

Comment: My answer was for a Relative Layout. This attribute will not work for a Linear Layout

Comment: Did you actually say that you were talking about a RelativeLayout? If so, I do not see it. But I do not mind taking away the down-vote. There is no reason to be so quick to take offence. I will entertain the suggestion that I am wrong about something.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following attribute in your text view:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/your_image_view_id"
```

Just make sure your ImageView is declared in your xml before the TextView and you give it an id (as an example, `android:id="@+id/your_image_view_id"`).

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your question.  Didn't realize that the image takes up the entire parent.  Use @heLL0's answer, but also use android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to put the text in the top right corner of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are wanting to "Overlay" the text views on top of the Image?

I.E. The image occupies the entire parent view and the text views align with the top and left edges of the image..

If that is the case you probably want something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/superawesomeimage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/photoofmyholiday" />

     <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/superawesomeimage"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/superawesomeimage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should produce a textView along (the top by default) of the image, matching the image width of the image *container* (to make the image fully occupy the imageview you will need to specify a scale I think (fitXY probably).

I might be a bit off with the keywords/syntax here.. I was just typing it off the top of my head, but you get the general idea.

The important things to note are the order of the TextView/ImageView (it determines who is on top of whom) and the TextView layout alignment. With relative layouts you can position relative to other views.. so setting align left and align right to the image will make the left and right edges of the text view line up with the left and right edges of the image view. Hope that helps. Have fun!